# I have 5 carousels on one page wrapp

Tags: carousel

I have 5 carousels on one page in a tabs-content. The first one is working +/-, but if I delet a container-card from the 2 or 4 than all carousel are list up.

```
  <div class="tabs-content" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul class="tabs clearfix" data-tabgroup="first-tab-group">
                              <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">Indien</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab2">Himalaya</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab3">Sudostasien</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab4">Japan</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab5">China</a></li>
                            </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <section id="first-tab-group" class="tabgroup">
                            <div id="tab1">
                                <div class="popup hidden" id="popup">
                                  <img src="img/Indien/2691 Kopie.jpg" alt="Vergrößertes Bild">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="carousel-container">
                                 <div class="text-content"><div class="carousel1"></div>
                                     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="track">
            div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="img">17</div>
                    <div class="info"><p>your text or title</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="img">17</div>
                    <div class="info"><p>your text or title</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="arrow right material-icons"><span>keyboard_arrow_right</span></div>
        <div class="arrow left material-icons"><span>keyboard_arrow_left</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>

            </div>
        </div>
                             <div id="tab2">
                              <div class="text-content"><div class="carousel id="carousel2"">
                            </div>
                                <div class="popup hidden" id="popup2">
                                  <img src="img/himalaya/5646 Kopie.jpg" alt="Vergrößertes Bild">
                                   </div>
    <div class="carousel-container" id="carousel-container2">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="track">
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="img">17</div>
                    <div class="info"><p>your text or title</p></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="img">17</div>
                    <div class="info"><p>your text or title</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-container">
                <div class="card">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="nav">
        <div class="arrow right material-icons"><span></span></div>
        <div class="arrow left material-icons"><span>></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/js2.js"></script>
```

Here the java-code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    console.log("Popup element: ", popup);

    const popupImage = popup.querySelector('img');
    console.log("Popup image element: ", popupImage);

    // Überprüfen Sie, ob die Elemente korrekt ausgewählt wurden

    const preloadedImages = {};

    // Fügen Sie eine Verzögerung hinzu, bevor das Popup ausgeblendet wird
    let popupTimeout;

    document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container').forEach(container => {
        console.log("Carousel container found");

        const left = container.querySelector('.left');
        console.log("Left arrow element: ", left);

        const right = container.querySelector('.right');
        console.log("Right arrow element: ", right);

        const track = container.querySelector('.track');
        console.log("Track element: ", track);

        let carouselWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        console.log("Carousel width: ", carouselWidth);

        let index = 0;
        let sumOfRight = 0;

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            const newCarouselWidth = container.offsetWidth;
            if (newCarouselWidth !== carouselWidth) {
                carouselWidth = newCarouselWidth;

                // Nachdem Sie die Container-Cards ausgewählt haben
                const containerCardWidth = container.offsetWidth;

                // Berechnen Sie die Breite des Tracks basierend auf der Breite der Container-Cards
                const trackWidth = container.querySelectorAll('.card').length * containerCardWidth;
                track.style.width = trackWidth + 'px';

                // Überprüfen Sie die Breite des Tracks und passen Sie die Bewegung entsprechend an
                if (trackWidth - (index * containerCardWidth) < containerCardWidth) {
                    right.classList.add('hide');
                } else {
                    right.classList.remove('hide');
                }
            }
        });

        right.addEventListener('click', function () {
            index++;
            left.classList.add('show');
            sumOfRight = sumOfRight + carouselWidth;

            // Überprüfen, ob das Carousel das Ende erreicht hat
            if ((sumOfRight + carouselWidth) < track.offsetWidth) {
                track.style.transform = `translate(-${sumOfRight}px)`;
            } else {
                // Springe am Anfang zurück, wenn das Ende erreicht ist
                sumOfRight = 0;
                index = 0;
                track.style.transform = `translate(-${sumOfRight}px)`;
            }

            // Überprüfen, ob der rechte Pfeil ausgeblendet werden soll
            if (track.offsetWidth - (index * carouselWidth) < carouselWidth) {
                right.classList.add('hide');
            }
        });

        left.addEventListener('click', function () {
            sumOfRight -= carouselWidth;
            index--;
            right.classList.remove('hide');
            if (index === 0) {
                left.classList.remove('show');
            }

            if (sumOfRight >= 0) {
                track.style.transform = `translate(-${sumOfRight}px)`;
            } else {
                track.style.transform = `translate(-${0}px)`;
                sumOfRight = 0;
            }
        });

        // Vorladen der Bilder für das Popup
        container.querySelectorAll('.card img').forEach(img => {
            const src = img.src;
            if (!preloadedImages[src]) {
                const preloadImage = new Image();
                preloadImage.src = src;
                preloadedImages[src] = preloadImage;
            }
        });

        // Mouseover Eventlistener für Bilder
        container.querySelectorAll('.card img').forEach(img => {
            img.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                img.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
                img.style.transition = 'transform 0.3s ease';

                // Setze das Popup-Bild nur, wenn es sich ändert
                if (popupImage.src !== img.src) {
                    popupImage.src = img.src;
                }

                popup.classList.remove('hidden');

                // Löschen Sie die vorherige Verzögerung (falls vorhanden) und setzen Sie eine neue Verzögerung für das Ausblenden des Popups
                clearTimeout(popupTimeout);
            });

            // Mouseout Eventlistener für Bilder
            img.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                img.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
                
                // Verzögern Sie das Ausblenden des Popups
                popupTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    popup.classList.add('hidden');
                }, 300); // Passen Sie die Verzögerungszeit nach Bedarf an
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here the CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

.carousel-container1 {
    width: 100%; /*use media query*/
    margin: 10px auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
}
.carousel-container2 {
    width: 100%; /*use media query*/
    margin: 10px auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    direction: ltr;
}
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {.carousel-container {
        width: 80%;
    }}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {.carousel-container {
        width: 80%;
    }}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {.carousel-container {
        width: 80%;
    }}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {.carousel-container {
        width: 85%;
    }}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {.carousel-container {
        width: 85%;
    }}

.carousel-container .track {
    display: inline-flex;
    transition: transform 2s;
}
.carousel-container .card-container {
    width: 298px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*border: 1px solid orange;*/
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    direction: rtl;
    left: 86px;
}
.carousel-container .card-container .card {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.carousel-container .carousel-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav .arrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f7c552;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav div{
    background: rgba(222,222,222,0.6);
}
.nav div:hover{
    background: rgba(222,222,222,0.2);
}
.nav div span{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #f7c552;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav .right {
    right: 30px;
}

.nav .left {
    left: -30px;
    display: none;
}
.nav .right.hide {
    display: none;
}

.nav .right.show {
    display: block;
}
.nav .left.show {
    display: block;
}
.card > * {
    flex: 0;
}
.card .img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.card img {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
.card .info {
    flex-basis: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.card img {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.card-container .card img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.card-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 33.33%;
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* Flexbox-Eigenschaften für flexible Größe */
    width: 300px; /* Breite jeder Card, kann angepasst werden */
    margin-right: 10px; /* Abstand zwischen den Cards */
}

.card-container:hover .card img {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: nanpx;
}

.table-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.table-container:hover .card img {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 3; /* Stellen Sie sicher, dass das vergrößerte Bild über anderen Elementen liegt */
}

.popup {
    position: fixed; /* Position festlegen, um über allem zu liegen */
    top: 50%; /* Zentrieren Sie das Bild vertikal */
    left: 50%; /* Zentrieren Sie das Bild horizontal */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Zentrieren Sie das Bild genau in der Mitte */
    z-index: 9999; /* Stellen Sie sicher, dass das Popup über allen anderen Elementen liegt */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Hintergrundfarbe für das Popup */
    padding: 20px; /* Innenabstand für das Bild */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Runde Ecken für das Popup */    
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: auto; /* Falls das Popup scrollbar sein muss */
}

.popup img {
    max-width: 80vw; /* Maximale Breite des Bildes auf 80% der Viewport-Breite begrenzen */
    max-height: 80vh; /* Maximale Höhe des Bildes auf 80% der Viewport-Höhe begrenzen */
    display: block; /* Sicherstellen, dass das Bild zentriert angezeigt wird */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Zentrieren Sie das Bild horizontal */
}

/* Verstecken Sie das Popup standardmäßig */
.popup.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I can't find the error why the carousels are not staying in the tab1, or tab2 and so one when I am deleting a container-card.